# Ant try to compile to 1.6 when target is set to 1.5

Tags: java, ant, javac

I am struggling with javac ant task problem for a really long time now. The problem is with that apparently ant is ignoring target attribute which is set to 1.5:

```
    <target name="compile" description="Kompilacja zrodel" depends="init">
    <javac target="${compile.targetvm}" source="${compile.sourcecompatibility}" debug="${compile.debug}" optimize="${compile.optimize}" verbose="${compile.verbose}" srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${build.classes.dir}" encoding="${compile.source.encoding}" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>
```

The target and source is set to 1.5.
When i run the task i have compile error:

```
foo.Bar is not abstract and does not override abstract method createStruct(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object[]) in java.sql.Connection
```

According to java docs ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStruct(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[]))) method createStruct was introduced in java 1.6 so i know that ant is compiling to 1.6 and not to 1.5 as i polite ask him to do.

I was running the task from eclipse and from command line with same result so it's not eclipse problem. I was trying to change the JRE in ANT and to use different ANT versions and nothing helped.

I have tried everything that i could find on web and now i give up. Could someone help me? Pretty please..

Comment: Specifying source compatibility only controls the language syntax, not the Java Runtime Library. Since you haven't told Ant where to find a Java 1.5 Runtime Library, it is using the same library used to invoke Ant.

Comment: To fix, specify the `bootclasspathref="compile.bootclasspath"`, after specifying `<path id="compile.bootclasspath"><fileset dir="${java15.home}/jre/lib" includes="*.jar"/></path>`

Comment: Yes! That works! Thank you so much:) You should put this as Answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 0):

Specifying source compatibility only controls the language syntax, not the Java Runtime Library.

Since you haven't told Ant where to find a Java 1.5 Runtime Library, it is using the same library used to invoke Ant.

To fix, specify the `bootclasspathref="compile.bootclasspath"` attribute too.

`compile.bootclasspath` is defined like this:

```xml
<path id="compile.bootclasspath">
    <fileset dir="${java15.home}/jre/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
```

It should be obvious what `java15.home` is. ;-)